# How to use two way data binding in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, data-binding

In MVVM pattern, if we want to pass the data from the controller to ViewModel and ViewModel to the controller we need to use the data binding. To achieve the data binding there are some techniques like Rx, KVO. I’ve found some samples using the Rx and I don’t want to use that. How can we use the MVVM binding in a better way? And In this MVVM where we implement the navigation(Push) code?

Comment: Check this if it helps : https://codeburst.io/swift-mvvm-two-way-binding-win-b447edc55ff5